# How can I have link text with a URL in Pod's L<>?

Tags: perl, perl-pod

The `L<name>` formatting code allows you to set the display text for the link if you're linking to other POD, as in `L<Display Text|link_dest>`, but this isn't allowed for `L<scheme:...>` links, such as

```
L<http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html>
```

How do I specify a display text for such links?  Alternatively, how do I manually write such a link without the angle brackets being HTML entitized by `pod2html`?

Answer (score 6):

The proper format is this:

```
L<strict|http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html>
```

See also http://justatheory.com/computers/programming/perl/sane-pod-links.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something fancy with your Pod, it's really easy to write a Pod translator. Most of the work is already done for you in Pod::Simple, so you only need to handle the cases for `L<>`. There's a chapter in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/) about it.

Answer (score 1):

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html#Formatting-Codes

```
L<<a href="http://www.perl.org/">http://www.perl.org/</a>>
```

As you point out, it looks like this should work, but perhaps I've misunderstood your question?

EDIT:
It seems that pod2html does not like that approach.
I found a slightly more involved solution at,

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/howdoi/?p=114

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                              
use strict;
use warnings;
use Pod::2::html;


my $pod_file =  $ARGV[0];
my $template =  $ARGV[1];

# Create pod2html object                                                                                                    
my $pod = Pod::2::html->new($pod_file);

# The path to the HTML template                                                                                             
$pod->template($template);

# The formatted HTML will go to STDOUT                                                                                      
$pod->readpod();
```

I tested this out and it seems to have no problem interpolating generic html, so that you don't actually need th L<> tag at all.
This seems like a decent solution to me.

Comment: I tried this with this construct — L<<a href="http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html">foo</a>> but running pod2html gives the following error: /opt/local/bin/pod2html: debugging.pod: cannot resolve L<<a href="http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html"> in paragraph 6.

Am I doing something blatantly wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You were SO close! You're missing a required space between both angle brackets and the URL. Try this:

```
I think L<< http://example.com >> is the best site on the web!
```

The extra space is mandatory according to `perldoc perlpod` (scroll down from [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html#Formatting-Codes) to find it):

> *"A more readable, and perhaps more "plain" way is to use an alternate set of delimiters that doesn't require a single ">" to be escaped.  With the Pod formatters that are standard starting with perl5.5.660, doubled angle brackets ("<<" and ">>") may be used if and only if there is whitespace right after the opening delimiter and whitespace right before the closing delimiter!  For example, the following will do the trick:"*

```
       C<< $a <=> $b >>
```

Comment: Almost there—using that style works in pod2text (perldoc), but pod2html chokes.  The format I'm using is L<< Strict doc|http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html >>.